# Apache-JMeter 5.4

Tags: jmeter, openjdk-11

I set an open JDK version in my pc to run JMeter. I was confirmed that jdk installation is fine by "java -version" command. Till now, all going well. But when I tried to run Jmeter.bat file a cmd interface appears that is irreversible.
Here is the screenshot. (https://prnt.sc/x8endi)
Is JMeter 5.4 is compatible with Open JDK version(11.0.2)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to click "Alt-Tab" to switch to JMeter GUI?

[image]

I think you're suffering from a side-effect of fixing bugs [62179](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62179) and [64658](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64658) so now JMeter doesn't bring itself into focus. If you don't think this behaviour is acceptable you can raise an [issue](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

Alternatively you can downgrade to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/), previous versions of JMeter can be obtained from [JMeter Archives page](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/)